# Need help regarding a PHP/SQL login function

Tags: php, sql

Before you say it: I know the passwords should be encrypted/hashed, but I want to get this down first:
I have this login function and a SQL database.  However, the login function doesn't seem to work and I haven't the faintest idea why.  I am probably missing something stupid, but have been struggling with this for a while now.  Any help would be appreciated!

**NOTE: the file db_connect.php is really just a basic connecting to the database, nothing wrong there**

FUNCTION.PHP:

```
<?
function login($username, $password, $con) 
{       
    $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE Username = '$username' and Password = '$password';";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $myQuery);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else
    {
return true;
    }
}
?>
```

PROCESS-LOGIN.PHP:

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['pword'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['pword']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($username, $password) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: welcome.html');
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: index.html');
    }
} 
else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
?>
```

Comment: Get into the habit, when using database calls, of testing at _every_ stage of the process. When you connect, test the connection. When you prepare a query, test the result. When you run a query, test the result. When you fetch results, test that too! The function `mysqli_query` returns `false` if there's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing MySQL**i** (`mysqli_query`) with  MySQL (`mysql_num_rows`) - decide for either one (preferably the former).

If you are using MySQL, the parameters for `mysql_query` are in wrong order.

In addition to that you are failing to pass the connection to the `login` as a parameter (as [WoLfulus mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20483017/1557526)).

---

Some additional info as you seem to be learning:

- The `return` statement of `login` can be simplified to `return mysql_num_rows($result) == 1;`. This will return `TRUE` if one record was found and `FALSE` otherwise - no need for an `if/else` statement here, you already have the logic you need.
- Right now anyone can access `welcome.html` without logging in by simply typing the address in the browser. This can be avoided by using [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).
- Since you don't properly escape the user input (which one should never trust!), you are vulnerable to SQL injections. `mysql_real_escape_string` is a start but [no 100% solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). If you used [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.prepare.php) on the other hand, you wouldn't need to worry.

Comment: thanks for the response but its still not working.  I added $con and standardized to mysql_*.  Still does not work...

Comment: "Does not work" is awfully vague. Do as halfer said in the comment on your question and try to debug as much as possible. Make use of `mysql_error()` as well

Comment: Sorry.  There is no error being returned.  Debugging is proving unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing the $con parameter to login function.

```
function login($username, $password, $con)
```

You are calling it as

```
login($username, $password)
```

Try providing the connection argument to see if it works.

Also note the answer kingkero made. You are using functions from different libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Some things I noticed

- Are you using `method="POST"` in your form?
- Your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injections
- your mixing mysql_* with mysqli_* functions
- missing `$con` parameter for login function

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering since I don't have enough reputation to comment your question.. But you should keep your variables outside the quotes and add mysql_real_escape_string() to prevent mysql injection..

```
$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE Username = '$username' and Password = '$password';";
```

Should be:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE Username = '". mysql_real_escape_string($username) ."' and Password = '". mysql_real_escape_string($password) ."';";
```

Comment: Why? Inside double quotes it is ok to have variables, is it not?

Comment: No! It's not - have a look at prepared statements or escaping: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @Philipp My comment was just about the concatenation contra to having it inside the query (as halfer mentioned). Also [`mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't fully protect against SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)